# Wigner functions, symmetry

Tags: quantum-optics, phase-space, wigner-transform

I'm trying to get more insight into quasiprobability distributions, as for example the Wigner function.

There are some Wigner functions, which are symmetric.

**Symmetric:**

Fock state

Thermal states

Vacuum states

**Non symmetric:**

Coherent states

What's the interpretation of that? Does every state which is diagonal in the Fock basis has a symmetric Wigner function?

Comment: What do you mean by symmetric? And also quasi-distribution functions are defined for operators not for states. Could give some example of what you have in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You might firm up your intuition from this [gallery of WFs](http://www.iqst.ca/quantech/wiggalery.php). The idea for Fock space stationary states is that they are expansions around the vacuum, the ground state of the axially (*x-p*) symmetric oscillator Hamiltonian so they are symmetric. That is, if by "diagonal in Fock space" you mean eigenstates of the number operator, in phase space that simply amounts to $\star$-genstates of the oscillator hamiltonian, so, then, axially symmetric by eqn (43) in our book, [Thomas L. Curtright, David B. Fairlie, & Cosmas K. Zachos, *A Concise Treatise on Quantum Mechanics in Phase Space*, World Scientific, 2014](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/a.pdf) on the subject.

A coherent state, by contrast, *not a Hamiltonian eigenstate*, amounts to translating the center of these configurations, to a desired *new center*, by a phase-space translation operator, so they are *defined* to be [asymmetric about the vacuum](http://www.physics.miami.edu/~curtright/TimeDependentWignerFunctions.html);
although, of course, they have a ***new center of axial symmetry*** (Behold!).

Likewise, as the name implies, squeezed states are asymmetric.

Other configurations will, in general, lack axial symmetry, unless they are eigenstates of an *x-p* symmetric Hamiltonian.

Note, however, in general, a [non-stationary configuration](http://www.physics.miami.edu/~curtright/TimeDependentWignerFunctions.html)  of the oscillator, an oscillating particle, so then a rigidly rotating configuration, is not symmetric——except when [time-averaged](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/a.pdf).

Comment: the first link appears to be broken

Comment: Indeed, the http://iqst.ca/index.php galleries have suffered link rot. Try [this one](http://gerdbreitenbach.de/gallery/) instead .